# Download file without opening download dialog

Tags: javascript, servlets, browser

## The Problem:

I need to force the download dialog not to open in a browser when in a downloading process:

I have the server *code* like any other download *servlet*.
On the client side I have a *link* that points to the *servlet* like any other download *link*.

Is there a way to download automatically when clicking on the link without opening the dialog?

What I think is that it may be related to the following:

1. Server code (*Java*) ?
2. Client code (*JavaScript*) ?
3. Browser settings ?
4. Browser type ?

## The Purpose behind this:

There is a website that belongs to this company where it is fortified with a high security wall clearing out the chance of downloading any virus.

The clients of this site need to have the download link saving automatically when clicked on.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you want to cache data, build a download manager or download a virus and execute it ;)? Maybe if you give us more details, we can make better suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't interact with files on *HDD* from a *browser* without notifying the *user*. It's a security policy.

Comment: But Google Chrome never asks me in the default config for some types of files. I've configured to always ask me the download folder.

Comment: This depends on browser configuration, not on serverside.

Comment: You cannot modify them unless you have control over the clients. An in that case you'd have to enable this for all downloads which would be a pretty bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, you want the browser to download your file on a default folder without asking you where?

Well, I think that, this depends on your browser, maybe you can customize the configuration in order to set a default download folder, but, I think it is not possible to force it on the server side.

Comment: @Hugo: all browsers have default download folder.
i think the user wants to download the document to that folder, but does not want the dilaog to appear and ask him to open/save, that's all !!